# Postgres smallint[] into java short[] array

Tags: java, sql, arrays, postgresql, classcastexception

I have a database table in PostgreSQL with a column named 'data' and type: `smallint[]`

I am trying to save data from the query to a java `short[]` and I am getting the following exception:

> java.lang.ClassCastException: class [Ljava.lang.Integer; cannot be cast to class [I ([Ljava.lang.Integer; and [I are in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap')"

My implementation:

```
String sql = "SELECT * FROM table"
res = executeQuery(stmt, temp);

        ArrayList<VO> vos = new ArrayList<>();
        while (res.next()) {
            VO vo = new VO();
            Array ar = res.getArray("data");
            // vo has a private member data : short[]
            vo.setData((short[]) ar.getArray());
        }
```

Exception is thrown @`vo.setData((short[]) ar.getArray());`, where I am trying to cast the  `java.sql.Array` into a `short[]` array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

from the error message, it seems `getArray` returns an `Integer[]`. You'll have to convert it to a `short[]` manually:

```
Integer[] arr = (Integer[]) ar.getArray();
short[] data = new short(arr.length);
for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; ++i) {
    data[i] = arr[i].shortValue();
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. That really worked. I was stuck for many hours :p . I thought I had tried this solution.